# Will a switched neutral cause an open neutral on the remainder of the circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring

I have 2 switches that have a neutral(white) wire attached as well as a hot(black).When I unhooked the white the switch doesn't work ( light doesn't come on).I found this during tracing an open neutral,which starts at a receptacle after these switches.Not enough voltage foranything to work after to end of the circuit.

Answer (score 2):

What you have is most likely a switch loop. The wire may be white but it is not a neutral. It is switched hot. It should have the wire marked with black or red tape .

Since it is part of the hot side circuit to a light it is not connected to the neutral part of your wiring.  If it was it would cause a short and open the breaker when the switch was closed.

You will have to continue to look for the disconnection in the neutral run. It possibly can be in the box for the light fixture.

Answer (score 2):

You have a white wire being used as a hot wire.

At the light fixture you will find that white to be connected to the black hot from the panel.

While neutral must be white, white does not always mean neutral.  You have a switch loop.

If using a three light tester to find open neutral, I suggest getting a multi-meter and checking voltages between the wires.

Should have ~120v between hot and neutral, and hot to ground.  ~0v between neutral and ground for US system.  Readings much different from this should narrow down the problem.